# setOnItemClickListener for ListView in a fragment

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, android-fragments, onclicklistener

I'm having problems clicking on ListView items in the fragments. I wrote the code so the fragments point to layout files for everything and inside the 2 of the layouts are ListViews, which retrieve their entries from items in a string array in the strings.xml. I could not find a way to implement a setOnItemClickListener for each ListView item in my case due to the way I wrote the code.

MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.test_app;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.view.Menu;

public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity{
    ViewPager ViewPager = null;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        ViewPager= (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        FragmentManager fragmentManager=getSupportFragmentManager();
        ViewPager.setAdapter(new AdapterActivity(fragmentManager));
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
    }
}
```

AdapterActivity.java

```
package com.example.test_app;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

public class AdapterActivity extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter{
    public AdapterActivity(FragmentManager fm){
        super(fm);
    }
    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int i){
        Fragment fragment=null;
        if(i==0){
            fragment=new HomeFragment();
        }
        if(i==1){
            fragment=new CommunityFragment();
        }
        if(i==2){
            fragment=new ResourcesFragment();
        }
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount(){
        return 3;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position){
        if(position==0){
            return "Home Page";
        }
        if(position==1){
            return "Community";
        }
        if(position==2){
            return "Resources";
        }
        return null;
    }
}
class HomeFragment extends Fragment{
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState){
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.home_fragment, container, false);
    }
}
class CommunityFragment extends Fragment{
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState){
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.community_fragment, container, false);
    }
}
class ResourcesFragment extends Fragment{

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState){
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.resources_fragment, container, false);
    }
}
```

Then in the resources_fragment.xml layout, there is a ListView

```
<ListView
        android:id="@+id/resourcesListView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:entries="@array/categories" >
</ListView>
```

It grabs entries from strings.xml

```
<string-array name="categories">
        <item>Category 1</item>
        <item>Category 2</item>
        <item>Category 3</item>
        <item>Category 4</item>
        <item>Category 5</item>
        <item>Category 6</item>
        <item>Category 7</item>
        <item>Category 8</item>
</string-array>
```

I used [this link to create my ListView](http://theopentutorials.com/tutorials/android/listview/android-creating-and-populating-listview-items-in-xml/), but the setOnItemClickListener won't work for me. How else can I connect each listview item other activities?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The place to add your ListView.SetOnItemClickListener is in your fragment creation code, after you inlfate the layouts.  Use findViewById to find your ListView, and add your setOnItemClick listener.

```
class ResourcesFragment extends Fragment{

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState){

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.resources_fragment, container, false);
        ListView lv = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.mylistviewid);

        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                    int position, long arg3) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                        String category = categories[position];
                        Class activityClass = lookupActivityClass_byName(category);
                        //You could lookup by position, but "name" is more general

                        Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), activityClass);
                        startActivity(intent);


            }
        });

        return view;

    }
```

Comment: Thanks so much! I've just started learning android development so this is a little tough to understand. However I'm not quite sure how the contents of onItemClick will work. I want each list item to start a new activity when clicked, so I will create a class for each category, and each class will start a new activity. How would I write the code inside onItemClick for each list item?

Comment: The code I added in the onItemClick provides an outline of what you need to do.

Comment: I think I get it, am I supposed to add a String Array before String category = categories[position]? Ex: String categories[] = {"Category 1", "Category 2", "Category 3", "Category 4", "Category 5", "Category 6", "Category 7", "Category 8"}; But lookupActivityClass_byName is still "undefined for the type new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener(){}

Comment: yup, the lookup is a function to implement, takes a name, outputs the matching activity.class.  You can implement the lookup by position too if u think integers are easier (e.g. you can switch() on an integer).

Comment: Ok so i just create a method for it and basically have it return a class depending on the constructor?

Comment: depending on the argument* (functions don't have constructors) :)  but yeah, u need a way to select the class based on one of u'r variables (like position, name, etc).

Comment: I decided to use int position instead of strings so as there are 8 ListView items, is int position from 0-7 or 1-8? Also how do I return a class in the method: "private Class<?> lookupActivityClass_byName(int position)" ? I created a switch(position) but in the cases how do I return my activity class? For example I set up ResourceActivity.class. Thanks!

Comment: return from the function something like "ActivityMain.class" on each case of the switch, and in the definition use "Class" as the return type -- and position is zero based;

Comment: Hi, I was facing the issue related to this post, but i don't whether its possible in android or not, Let me explain what the difficulty i'm facing, ViewPager--->ListView(In Fragment, apply OnItemClick for list view )--->Child list view. I have this flow, please help me resolve this. I need sample code. Can you please share your ideas Thanks in Advance. Sorry for my flow explanation is not clear.

Answer (score 3):

When you use `Fragment`, you can find views inside `onCreateView()`. In simpler term, it's same as of `onCreate()` of `Activity`.

So in this case, find `ListView` inside `onCreateView()` and assign `onItemClickListener` there only.