# How to set onItemClickListener for ListView in a fragment?

Tags: java, android, listview, android-fragments

I try do it with below code but it not working! Please help me... I am confused ...
In below code all things is good but `onItemClickListener` is useless and it is in `onCreateView` method is wrong?
My items layout is not problem..

```
public class favFrg extends Fragment {

    View v;
    ListView listView;
    List<HashMap<String,Object>> listFav;
    DatabaseManager dbManager;

    public favFrg() {

        // Required empty public constructor
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        v= inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_fav_frg, container, false);
        listView= v.findViewById(R.id.listViewFav);

        dbManager=new DatabaseManager(getContext());
        dbManager.openDB();

        listFav=dbManager.getStoryFavorite();
        dbManager.closeDB();

        String[] keys={"id","txtName"};
        int[] resources={R.id.favTxtViewNumberStory,R.id.favTxtViewTitleStory};

        SimpleAdapter adapter=new SimpleAdapter(getContext(),listFav,R.layout.fav_item_layout,keys,resources);

        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
        Log.i("ListView","Adapter Set");

        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                Log.i("ListView","click item");




                Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"Clicked",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


            }
        });



        Log.i("ListView","Return View");
        return  v;
    }


    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


    }
```

Comment: try to apply click listener on Item view "V" in your case

Comment: pass "this" at listView.setOnItemClickListener() and override  @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) { } and handle click from here.

Comment: Please check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22164359/setonitemclicklistener-for-listview-in-a-fragment) to your answer.

Comment: share your error logcat

Comment: check this link https://code.i-harness.com/en/q/1561bd1

Comment: Thank you Bhuvaneshwaran Vellingiri  it works and solved

Answer (score 0):

instead of `getContext()` use `container.getContext()` in creating adapter for listview.

Answer (score 0):

Just Only clickable and focusable attr in my item layout should be false... and works for me

https://code.i-harness.com/en/q/1561bd1

Answer (score -1):

Try making the SimpleAdapter as a public variable and put it outside the class onCreateView

Comment: This should be a comment.